# Django - NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to get into Django by following the base tutorial but changing it a but to make into something I would actually use.

I have these urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from budget import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^category/$', views.category, name='category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', views.category_detail, name='category_details')
)
```

and

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^budget/', include('budget.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And then I have the following template:

```
{% if all_categories_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for category in all_categories_list %}
        <li><a href="/budget/category/{{category.id}}/">{{ category.category_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

And this from views.py

```
def category(request):
    all_categories_list = Budget_category.objects.order_by('category_type')
    context = {'all_categories_list': all_categories_list}
    return render(request, 'budget/category_list.html', context)
```

Now what I want to do is to remove the hardcoded /budget/category/ from the template and replace it with the url keyword to make it more flexible.

So change the line in the template to this

```
<li><a href="{% url 'category' category.id %}">{{ category.category_text }}</a></li>
```

But that gives an error of the type on localhost/budget/category/

```
NoReverseMatch at /budget/category/
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['budget/category/$']
```

Now I know this has something to do with either namespaces or the regular expressions ( I think so at least) but I seem to have not enough insight yet to see the issue. Cause this link localhost/budget/category/1/ does work the way it should. So why won't it build that link properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your url is `category_details`, not the `category`.  So change the `{% url %}` tag to:

```
{% url 'category_details' category.id %}
```

Comment: Eh, I am an idiot. I had tried that, but had the editor window on half the screen and saw it as category_detail instead of category_details. And I missed it again when copying it in here.

Well I guess that will teach for taking a 3 day break in the middle of learning. That fixed the issue :) Thanks a lot!